# Rails: format.js or format.json, or both?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

Might be obvious, but still I'm lacking here of the basic knowledge.

So inside controllers, can both be used, or is it always Javascript, so both are the same?

Comment: I believe that both can be used because they're separate MIME types. Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Rails 3.1 the only difference I can spot is that the if formatter is js, then the answer is sent as plain text. If it is json then it is encoded as json.

if format.json

```
format.json {
  render :json => @accounts.map(&:attributes)
}
```

server send:

```
data:application/json;base64,
```

if format.js

```
format.js {
  render :json => @accounts.map(&:attributes)
}
```

server send:

```
[{"id":33,"email":"user1@example.com"}]
```

Answer (score 41):

`json` and `js` are two different types of response and they are defined as different MIME types in Rails

```
Mime::Type.register "text/javascript", :js, %w( application/javascript application/x-javascript )
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :json, %w( text/x-json application/jsonrequest )
```

Even if Json can be considered a subset of JavaScript, not all JavaScript responses are actually Json responses.

You might want to respond with Json and Js in the same action.

For instance, you might have an action that responds with Json to an API call and with JavaScript (perhaps using RJS) to an internal Ajax call.