# Rails Edge Guides, AJAX example- why use both 'format.js' and 'format.json'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

In the ["Working With Javascript" section of the Rails Edge Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html), an example is given of how to structure a 'create' action inside a 'User' controller, in order to integrate AJAX into the creation action:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
# ......
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335985/rails-format-js-or-format-json-or-both) that both 'format.js' and 'format.json' are needed, because Javascript and JSON are different types of response.  My question is, if both formats are specified in the first half of the 'create' action's if statement, why aren't both also needed in the 2nd half?  Does this mean that Javascript uses the 'create.js.erb' file on success, but not on failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Based on skimming the guide, it looks like you don't want to do anything with js in the case of failure.  If you were to put

```
format.js   {}
```

in the failure block as well, then it would try to execute the `render @user` portion, which would probably cause an error anyway.

If you really did want to execute a js block in the event of failure, you could just do it the same way as for the other formats.